# Ionic Native Calendar

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic native calendar to display events. In LG, Samsung phones which has Android version 5.1.1 and more than those events not load properly. But events load in browser. Here i have attached the image  also.
I am retrieving data from PHP  server via ajax post method.

Could you plz help me to solve this issue.

events load function in calendar.ts:

```
loadEvents(){

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost/calendarapp/moblieapp/get_appointments',
          data: { 'calendar_type': 'month', 'start': date_parameter, 'end': date_parameter },
          success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
              var startTime;
              var endTime;
              var startTimeDate = new Date(obj[i]['start']);
              var endTimeDate = new Date(obj[i]['end']);

              startTime = startTimeDate;
              endTime = endTimeDate;


              var title = obj[i]['title'];
             // rest of the code


         }

      }
    });

}
```

calendar.html

```
 <calendar [monthviewEventDetailTemplate]="template" [eventSource]="eventSource" [calendarMode]="calendar.mode" [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
    (onCurrentDateChanged)="onCurrentDateChanged($event)" (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)" (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
    (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)" step="30">
  </calendar>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have data here `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);`?

Comment: Yes. data has json objects arrays